# HTML is not passing to PHP

Tags: php, html, post

I don't know why the form doesn't pass any information to the PHP function page.

HTML:

```
<form action="function.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="userid" class="textbox" data-placeholder="yes" value="Enter Your User ID Here" onfocus=" if (this.value == 'Enter Your User ID Here') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='Enter Your User ID Here';} " /><br /><br />


<input type="text" name="webid" class="textbox" data-placeholder="yes" value="Enter Your Webform ID Here" onfocus=" if (this.value == 'Enter Your Webform ID Here') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='Enter Your Webform ID Here';} " /><br /><br />

<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="Generate"  />
```

function.php:

```
<?php
$wid = $_POST['webid'];
$uid = $_POST['userid'];
if(isset($_POST['submit']))

if(isset($_POST['userid']) && isset($_POST['webid']))){

echo " You've done a successful job"
$link = "http://www.something.com".$uid."url&=".$wid;
echo $link;

}
?>
```

I kept getting

```
http:www.something.comurl&=
```

Comment: Missing `;` for `echo " You've done a successful job"` plus missing a `</form>` tag. You're also trying to echo as a GET method, when using POST. Also, use proper bracing methods. `http://www.something.com".$uid."url&=".$wid` few things missing in there, technically speaking.

Comment: The missing `</form>` will actually be auto-closed in practice, so isn't causing this problem. Still wrong ofc.

Comment: in if extra closing braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

You have a missing semi-colon in

```
echo " You've done a successful job"
                                    ^ right there
```

then one bracket too much for

```
if(isset($_POST['userid']) && isset($_POST['webid']))){
                                                     ^ right there
```

which would have produced a parse error.

Then this:

```
$link = "http://www.something.com".$uid."url&=".$wid;
```

there should be a `/` after `.com`

```
$link = "http://www.something.com/".$uid."url&=".$wid;
```

Plus, proper bracing techniques will help seperate the conditional statements:

```
$wid = $_POST['webid'];
$uid = $_POST['userid'];
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

if(isset($_POST['userid']) && isset($_POST['webid'])){

echo " You've done a successful job";
echo " - ";
$link = "http://www.something.com/".$uid."url&=".$wid;
echo $link;

    }

} // closing brace for if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

Plus, technically speaking, you're missing a closing `</form>` tag.

End results for this test was:

`You've done a successful job - http://www.something.com/1url&=test`

While using `1` and `test` in the form elements inputs.

---

- Always use [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) when coding.

Answer (score 0):

your form:

```
<form action="function.php" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="userid" class="textbox" data-placeholder="yes" value="Enter Your User ID Here" onfocus=" if (this.value == 'Enter Your User ID Here') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='Enter Your User ID Here';} " /><br /><br />


    <input type="text" name="webid" class="textbox" data-placeholder="yes" value="Enter Your Webform ID Here" onfocus=" if (this.value == 'Enter Your Webform ID Here') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='Enter Your Webform ID Here';} " /><br /><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="Generate"  />
    </form>
```

function.php:

```
<?php
$wid = $_POST['webid'];
$uid = $_POST['userid'];
if(isset($_POST['submit']))

if(isset($_POST['userid']) && isset($_POST['webid'])){

echo " You've done a successful job";
$link = "http://www.something.com".$uid."url&=".$wid;
echo $link;

}
?>
```